# How to use Material Dialogs in an Observable pipe sequence

Tags: angular, reactjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

For an application I'm rewriting from AngularJS, I have a sequence of actions:

```
1) I got to the server to get a message  
2) I display the returned message in a generic dialog, with a Yes and No button.  

3-Yes) I go to the server to do something, proceed to 4  
3-No) I terminate the sequence  

4) Notfiy the user that the operation is complete.
```

I'm having problems translating this to an Angular/React `Observable` system, hower.  I want to do something like this:

```
// Actual arguments are immaterial in this case...
this.webDataService.get('/api/GetEndUserMessage', args)
  .pipe(
    map((message: string) => {
      const config = new MatDialogConfig();
      config.data = {
        'title': 'Important',
        'message': message
      };
      const dialog = this.matDialog.open(GenericDialogComponent, config);
      // If Yes/Ok is clicked, return 'Ok'
      // If No/Cancel is clicked, return 'Cancel'

      return dialog.afterClosed();
    }),
    // PROBLEM AREA! ----------------------------------------------
    filter((dialogResult: string) => {
      if (dialogResult === 'Ok')
        return this.webDataService.post('/api/DoSomethingAwesome');
    }),
    filter((dialogResult: string) => {
      if (dialogResult !== 'Ok')
        return 'Cancelled'
    })
    // PROBLEM AREA! ----------------------------------------------
  )
  .subscribe((result: any) => {
    if (result === 'Cancelled')
      return;

    // Let the user know that the sequence is over.  How doesn't matter.
  });
```

The problem is, that apparently that doesn't compile.

My understanding of the React operator system is shaky at best, and I'm not sure how to invoke the Observable produced as a result of the `MatDialogRef.afterClosed()` call.

**Question:**
In what way can I use the results of a `MatDialogRef.afterClosed()` call in an `Observable .pipe` sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `switchMap` when you need to change Observable streams. The `map()` operator will just cause the observable to emit the returned value.

```
this.webDataService.get('/api/GetEndUserMessage', args)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((message: string) => {
        //...
        const dialog = this.matDialog.open(GenericDialogComponent, config);
        return dialog.afterClosed();
    }),
    switchMap((dialogResult: string) => {
        return (dialogResult === 'Ok')
            ? this.webDataService.post('/api/DoSomethingAwesome')
            : of('Cancelled')
    })
).subscribe((result: any) => { ... });
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: Won't this potentially leave multiple dialogs open, if new values are emitted? I thought the point of using switchMap that the first stream should be cancelled if a new value is emitted.

Comment: @JW. All the `HttpClient` methods will only emit a value once. What you say is true, but in this example the upstream observable emits only one value.